# Isomorphism of quaternion algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm reading Central Simple Algebras and Galois Cohomology by Gille and Szamuely. I am stuck on this line in one of the proof. $k$ is a field. A quaternion algebra is called *split* if it is isomorphic to $M_{2}(k)$ as a $k$-algebra.

This is the statement

> **Proposition 1.2.3** Consider a quaternion algebra $A$ over $k$, and fix and element $a\in k^{*}/k^{*^{2}}$. The following statements are equivalent:
>
> 1) $A$ is isomorphic to the quarternion algebra $(a,b)$ for some $k^{*}$.
>
> 2) The $k(\sqrt{a})$-algebra $A\otimes_{k} k(\sqrt{a})$ is split.

There is another part but that doesn't concern me. This is where I am stuck on the proof

> note that $(a,b)\otimes_{k}k(\sqrt{a})$is none but the quaternion algebra $(a,b)$ over $k(\sqrt{a})$.

I do not see this as obvious and can't seem to find the appropriate map. Any hints would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean "non**e** but the quaternion algebra"?

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar Yes, sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked in the book it goes on to say "none but the quaternion algebra $(a,b)$ over the algebra $k(\sqrt{a})$". This is just a change of the ground field. In the tensor product one still has exactly the same defining relations for the quaternion algebra, but now one has also scalar multiplication from this larger base field.

Edit:Yes you included this in you question now.

Comment: Great thanks. Simple misunderstanding of $(a,b)$.